# Computing $\alpha$ such that $\mathbb{E}[(\tfrac{\alpha}{X + \alpha})^2] = t$, for $t \in (0, 1)$?

Tags: roots, binomial-distribution, inverse-function

Suppose that $X$ is a Binomial random variable with parameters $n, p$.
Let
$$
F(\alpha) = \mathbb{E}\Big[\big(\frac{\alpha}{X + \alpha}\big)^2\Big], \quad 
\alpha > 0. 
$$
Clearly we have the limit relations
$$
\lim_{\alpha\to \infty} F(\alpha) = 1, \quad \mbox{and} \quad 
\lim_{\alpha \to 0} F(\alpha) = 0. 
$$
Let $t \in (0, 1)$. Is there a way to compute $F^{-1}(t)$? Equivalently,
$\alpha^\star(t)$ that solves
$$
F(\alpha) = t.
$$
The issue is that I do not see any way to really simplify the expression for $F(\alpha)$.

Comment: $F(\alpha)$ is strictly increasing so the solution will be unique. A few Newton-Raphson iterations will work.

Comment: As far as I see $F(0)=0$ and for large $\alpha$, $F(\alpha)\approx 1$. This looks strictly increasing to me. Newton Raphson only requires the calculation of $F'(\alpha)$. When $X$ is $B(n,p)$ there should be a implementable sum formula for $F(\alpha)$ and $F'(\alpha)$ that doesn't require MC. Just look up the binomial distribution in Wikipedia. Come back when you need help.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you're right. For some reason, I was considering it as a function of $X$, rather than $\alpha$. In this case, isn't it easier to just bisect on the interval using $F$ itself? Or is there a reason to expect Newton Raphson to converge more quickly.

Comment: (It appears the difference is $\log(1/\epsilon)$ versus $\log \log (1/\epsilon)$ iterations.)

Comment: Whatever works. We don't have the problem of multiple roots and NR is the one I am just more used to.